# Why first letter of a word in cryptarithmetic problem can't be 0?

Tags: puzzle, cryptarithm

I was given a cryptarithmetic problem by my teacher:
$$\mathrm{TWO}+\mathrm{TWO}=\mathrm{FOUR}$$

I solved it as *F=0, O=2, U=6, R=4, T=1 and W=3*.
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
&&&&1&3&2\\
+&&&&1&3&2\\
\hline
&&&0&2&6&4\\
\end{array}$$

But I was told that F can't be 0 because it is the first letter of the word.

Can anyone explain this to me? Why is there such a rule?

Comment: Otherwise, encrypted words are not unique: You may as well write FFFFFOUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because to be mathematically valid, a leading zero would be removed. $0123$ is actually $123$ in mathematics, for example.